# How does nodejs interpret key value pairs when no semi color exists and the key itself is a string called with a function?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, sinon, hexo

I was just going throw some of the test code in hexo-cli and came across the below lines of code ( full code and repo can be found [here](https://dn.myshopmatic.com/images/7ZEO4V/Rn2JYwED4q.jpg) ):

```
const hexo = proxyquire('../../dist/hexo', {
  './console'(ctx) {
    ctx.extend.console.register('help', spy);
  }
});
```

I have read articles online stating that the module can be proxied using `proxyquiry` ( [proxyquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) ) and then key-values can be passed to imitate the methods in these modules like below for example:

```
var calculateDiscounts = proxyquire(‘./somemodule’, {
  ‘*/cartridge/scripts/hooks/cart/calculateHelpers’: {
    removeAllPriceAdjustments: removeAllPriceAdjustmentsStub
  },
  ‘dw/campaign/PromotionMgr’: {
    getPromotion: getPromotionStub,
    getDiscounts: getDiscountsStub,
    applyDiscounts: applyDiscountsStub
  }
});
```

( [original article with above snippet](https://medium.com/ordergroove-engineering/unit-testing-with-chai-proxyquire-and-sinon-df0ecba75245) )

So how does the below line of code execute? Why no errors are thrown, since it doesn't seem like a valid object at all?

```
'./console'(ctx) {
   ctx.extend.console.register('help', spy);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as

```
'./console': function(ctx) {
   ctx.extend.console.register('help', spy);
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer?retiredLocale=pl#method_definitions or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Works fine in the broswer:

```js
const a = {
  './console'(num) {
    return num * 5
  }
}

console.log(a['./console'](2))
```

Comment: is this nodejs specific because if i try the same in the browser console i.e. without the `:` it will throw an error.